# read text file then add character to list?

Tags: c++, ifstream, void, words

So I'm trying to complete this part of a program where I have to read a text file from Stdin and add it to the 'word list' wl. I get how to read from a text file but I don't know how to go about adding 'words' to a list, if that makes sense. So here's what I got:

```
string getWord(){
    string word;
    while (cin >> word){
        getline(cin, word);
    }
    return word;
}

void fillWordList(string source[], int &sourceLength){
    ifstream in.file;
    sourceLength = 50;
    source[sourceLength]; ///this is the part I'm having trouble on
```

Source is an array that determines how many words are read from the text and length is the amount printed on screen.

Any ideas on what I should begin with?

EDIT: Here's the program I'm writing the implementation for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "ngrams.h"
void help(char * cmd) {
  cout << "Usage: " << cmd << " [OPTIONS] < INPUTFILE" << endl;
  cout << "Options:" << endl;
  cout << "  --seed RANDOMSEED" << endl;
  cout << "  --ngram NGRAMCOUNT" << endl;
  cout << "  --out OUTPUTWORDCOUNT" << endl;
}
string source[250000];
vector<string> ngram;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int n, outputN, sl;
  n = 3;
  outputN = 100;
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    if (string(argv[i]) == "--seed") {
      srand(atoi(argv[i+1]));
    } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--ngram") {
      n = 1 + atoi(argv[i+1]);
    } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--out") {
      outputN = atoi(argv[i+1]);
    } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--help") {
      help(argv[0]);
return 0; }
  }
  fillWordList(source,sl);
  cout << sl << " words found." << endl;
  cout << "First word: " << source[0] << endl;
  cout << "Last word:  " << source[sl-1] << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ngram.push_back(source[i]);
  }
  cout << "Initial ngram: ";
  put(ngram);
  cout << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < outputN; i++) {
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
  cout << endl;
}
//put(ngram);
//cout << endl;
cout << ngram[0] << " ";
findAndShift(ngram, source, sl);
} }
```

I'm supposed to use this as a reference but it dosen't help me too much.

Comment: The relation between your two functions is not clear. And I'm not quite sure about what you want to do with source and sourceLength.

Comment: @Sceptical Jule I'm a bit baffled on what to do with them as well. Here's a description from the header of what I'm supposed to do:

`string getWord();
// return a space-separated word from standard input`

`void fillWordList(string source[], int &sourceLength);
// read a text file from standard in and add all
// space-separated words to the word list wl`

Answer (score 1):

Declaring raw array requires the size of the array to be a compile-time constant. Use  `std::vector` or at least `std::array` instead. And pass `source` by reference if you want to fill it.